# Why does a ParseUser have been registered without a deviceToken?

Tags: android, parse-platform, devicetoken

I've experienced a strange thing in my Parse app: a new Installation record has been added, from an Android device, but its `deviceToken` field is blank. Probably for this, the new user doesn't receive any push notification (subscribers targeting his device are always zero).

Why this situation?

Comment: You mean the Installation record?

Comment: Yes, my fault. I've fixed the open post

Comment: Android devices use the installationId field.  Go through the troubleshooting steps here: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/Android

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. It turned out you **must** set `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, YourActivity.class);` (I thought it was optional). Tell me if it helps then I can post an answer.

Comment: I've already done it since the first steps of the development.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use installation table just to track installation of app across user devices, for example to handle loading data from other device ...